# Optimize mysql query joining table

Tags: jquery, mysql, query-optimization, loading, minimization

Please advice how to optimize below query and minimize query loading..

> $query = "select
>     lot.arc_id,lot.arc_mod0_kod_daerah,lot.arc_mod0_kod_mukim,lot.arc_mod0_no_dhm,lot.arc_mod0_no_lot,lot.arc_mod0_jenis_lot,lot.arc_mod0_jenis_dhm,status.arc_mod0_status_pembayar,
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik,
>   user.arc_mod0_no_kp_baru,user.arc_mod0_no_kp_lama,user.arc_mod0_no_syarikat,user.arc_mod0_nama,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_cukai_tanah,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_cukai_taliair,cukai.arc_mod0_denda,cukai.arc_mod0_notis6a,cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_dari,cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_hingga,cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_cukai_tanah,cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_taliair,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_denda,cukai.arc_mod0_tunggakan_notis6a,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_hapusan, cukai.arc_mod0_remisyen,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_remisyen_dari, cukai.arc_mod0_remisyen_hingga,
>   cukai.arc_mod0_status_bayar       from frmmod0_lot_info lot,
>   frmmod0_pihatpen status, frmmod0_pihak_be user, frmmod0_cukai_in cukai
>         where lot.arc_id=status.arc_mod0_lot_id AND
>   status.arc_mod0_pihak_id=user.arc_id AND
>   cukai.arc_mod0_lot_id=lot.arc_id AND
>   user.arc_mod0_no_syarikat='$company_no' AND
>   status.arc_mod0_status_aktif='1' AND lot.arc_mod0_lotstatus = '1' AND
>   (status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='01' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='02' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='05' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='06' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='10' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='12' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='13' OR
>   status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik='14')";

Comment: This is better asked at [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
  select * from frmmod0_lot_info lot left join frmmod0_pihatpen status on lot.arc_id=status.arc_mod0_lot_id
  left join frmmod0_pihak_be user on status.arc_mod0_pihak_id=user.arc_id
  left join frmmod0_cukai_in cukai on cukai.arc_mod0_lot_id=lot.arc_id
  where 
  user.arc_mod0_no_syarikat='$company_no' AND 
  status.arc_mod0_status_aktif='1' AND 
  lot.arc_mod0_lotstatus = '1' AND 
  (status.arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik in ('02','05','06','10','12','13','14',))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need these indexes:

```
user:   INDEX(arc_mod0_no_syarikat)
status: INDEX(arc_mod0_status_aktif, arc_mod0_pihak_id, arc_mod0_kod_taraf_pemilik)
lot:    INDEX(arc_mod0_lotstatus, arc_id)
```

Do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for what you have; look at the `Rows` column.  Repeat after adding these indexes.  The product of the `Rows` column will probably decrease dramatically.

[*More on creating optimal indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).